# context.SaveChanges() not persisting data in database

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc-3

Im working on a MVC app.

When I call context.SaveChanges to update a specific records. The update is not registered in the database. I do not get any runtime error either. All in notice is that my Records is not updated. I still see the same values. Insert Functionality work Perfectly.

```
enter code here

public Admission Update(int stuid){

        VDData.VidyaDaanEntities context = new VDData.VidyaDaanEntities();
        VDData.Student_Master studentmaster = new VDData.Student_Master();

        studentmaster.Student_ID = stuid;
        studentmaster.Student_First_Name = this.FirstName;
        studentmaster.Student_Middle_Name = this.MiddleName;
        studentmaster.Student_Last_Name = this.LastName;
        studentmaster.Student_Address_1 = this.Address;
        studentmaster.Student_Address_2 = this.Address2;
        studentmaster.Student_City = this.City;
        studentmaster.Student_State = this.State;
        studentmaster.Student_Pin_Code = this.Pincode;

       context.SaveChanges(); // here it wont give any kind of error. it runs sucessfully. }
```

Comment: you can provide some code !

Comment: Are you update the model before you save the changes?

Comment: Did you attach that entity? You can find something helpful here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592676.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you want to update, so your code should be

```
VDData.Student_Master studentmaster = context.Student_Masters.Single(p=>p.Student_ID == stuid);
```

And you should not change the Student_ID if it is the primary key.

```
public Admission Update(int stuid){

        VDData.VidyaDaanEntities context = new VDData.VidyaDaanEntities();
        //VDData.Student_Master studentmaster = new VDData.Student_Master();
//REPLACE WITH
VDData.Student_Master studentmaster = context.Student_Masters.Where(p=>p.Student_ID == stuid);

        studentmaster.Student_ID = stuid;
        studentmaster.Student_First_Name = this.FirstName;
        studentmaster.Student_Middle_Name = this.MiddleName;
        studentmaster.Student_Last_Name = this.LastName;
        studentmaster.Student_Address_1 = this.Address;
        studentmaster.Student_Address_2 = this.Address2;
        studentmaster.Student_City = this.City;
        studentmaster.Student_State = this.State;
        studentmaster.Student_Pin_Code = this.Pincode;

       context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: VDData.Student_Master studentmaster = context.Student_Masters.Where(p=>p.Student_ID == stuid);                                                                                                                                       it give the error Error Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<VDData.Student_Master>' to 'VDData.Student_Master'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)VDModel\Models\Admission\Admission.cs

Answer (score 1):

First get the entity you are going to update:

```
var entity = obj.GetEntity(id);
entity.col1 = "value";
context.SaveChanges(entity);
```

hope this will help.

Comment: Thank to respond me. i am trying your code but it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Before

```
context.SaveChanges();
```

You need to call this

```
context.Student_Masters.Add(studentmaster );
```

**Edit:** introduce `Abstraction` to your `Context class` and Create a method in your context class like below, then you can call it whenever you want to create or update your objects.

```
public void SaveStudent_Master(Student_Master studentmaster)
    {
        using (var context = new VDData.VidyaDaanEntities())
        {
            if (studentmaster.Student_ID == 0)
            {
                context.Student_Masters.Add(studentmaster);
            }
            else if (studentmaster.Student_ID > 0)
            {
                //This Updates N-Level deep Object grapgh
                 //This is important for Updates  
                var currentStudent_Master = context.Student_Masters
                    .Single(s => s.Student_ID == studentmaster.Student_ID );

                context.Entry(currentStudent_Master ).CurrentValues.SetValues(studentmaster);                  
            }
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
```

Then in your Controller replace `context.SaveChanges();` with `_context.SaveStudent_Master(studentmaster);`

Comment: Actually i want to update the records and your suggested code for Inserting a records into a table.

Comment: @Harshal yeah, i see that now, you didn't show enough code before